# Object reference giving undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please bear with me for my silly questions, i am new to javscript. I am trying to filter the map but unable to assign the created object to reference variable.

```
let serviceFeeMap = new Map();
  paymentAmountServiceFeeInfo.map(serviceFees => {
    if (serviceFees.serviceFees.serviceFeeApplicableMethods.length > 0) {
      serviceFees.serviceFees.serviceFeeApplicableMethods.map(applicableMethod => {
        let serviceFeeList = serviceFeeMap.get(applicableMethod);
        if (!serviceFeeList) {
          serviceFeeMap.set(applicableMethod, new Array(serviceFees.serviceFees));
        } else {
          serviceFeeList.push(serviceFees.serviceFees);
          serviceFeeMap.set(applicableMethod, serviceFeeList);
        }
      });
    }
  });



const finalResult = serviceFeeMap.forEach((v, k) => {
    let values = v;
    let count = 0;
    const arrayValues = values.map((value) => {
      if (count === 0) {
        count++;
         return {
           applicableMethod : k,
           serviceFeeAdjustmentType : value.serviceFeeAdjustmentType,
           serviceFeeAmount : value.serviceFeeAmount
         };
      } else {
        count++;
        return {
          applicableMethod : '',
          serviceFeeAdjustmentType : value.serviceFeeAdjustmentType,
          serviceFeeAmount : value.serviceFeeAmount
        };
      }

    })
    return arrayValues;
  });
```

I am getting finalResult as undefined .

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return a value from `forEach()` callback but it can't returns any value. The forEach() method executes a provided function once per each key/value pair in the Map object, in insertion order.

According to MDN [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach)

> The forEach method executes the provided callback once for each key of the map which actually exist. It is not invoked for keys which have been deleted. However, it is executed for values which are present but have the value undefined.

That's the reason you are getting `undefined` of `finalResult`. In this case you can write a global `var` to hold the iteration value of `Map.prototype.forEach()`

```
let finalResult = [];
serviceFeeMap.forEach((v, k) => {
    let values = v;
    let count = 0;
    const arrayValues = values.map((value) => {
        if (count === 0) {
            count++;
            return {
                applicableMethod : k,
                serviceFeeAdjustmentType : value.serviceFeeAdjustmentType,
                serviceFeeAmount : value.serviceFeeAmount
            };
        } else {
            count++;
            return {
                applicableMethod : '',
                serviceFeeAdjustmentType : value.serviceFeeAdjustmentType,
                serviceFeeAmount : value.serviceFeeAmount
            };
        }

    })
    finalResult.push(arrayValues);
})
```

Comment: Since we serviceFeeMap is a map, there is not method like map on Map in javascript

Comment: what `serviceFeeMap`? is not an array it?

Comment: It is an map object as you can see with name as well

Comment: See [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach). `Map.prototype.forEach()` doesn't return a value. So you can write a global var to store the iterated value from `map.forEach()`

Answer (score 0):

That is because `forEach` will return an `undefined`. You can use a `map` inside a `map` which will return array of arrys or create an array outside `forEach` and push `arrayValues` inside that

```js
const finalResult = serviceFeeMap.map((v, k) => {
  let values = v;
  let count = 0;
  return values.map((value) => {
    if (count === 0) {
      count++;
      return {
        applicableMethod: k,
        serviceFeeAdjustmentType: value.serviceFeeAdjustmentType,
        serviceFeeAmount: value.serviceFeeAmount
      };
    } else {
      count++;
      return {
        applicableMethod: '',
        serviceFeeAdjustmentType: value.serviceFeeAdjustmentType,
        serviceFeeAmount: value.serviceFeeAmount
      };
    }

  })

});
```

Comment: I am getting the error that serviceFeeMap.map is not a function